# Django receives wrong parameters

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I developed a test project using Django. It works well locally, but when I deploy to the build server, the parameters I receive are wrong.

I have an APP in this project. He receives a URL as a parameter and processes it. However, when I print the incoming parameters on the server, I find that a missing "/" causes the APP to fail to process the URL. For example, I type "https://v.douyin.com/GSW2Ab/" in the browser, and the server prints "https: /v.douyin.com/GSW2Ab/".

My Django project is deployed with Nginx + uwsgi. Is this a problem with nginx?

---

**client input**

[image]

---

**server**

[image]

---

**views.py**

[image]